# How to deal with users as foreign key and deletion

Tags: django

How do I deal with foreign keys like users or usernames that could one day be deleted?

My best guess would be a CharField with Choices limited to the Referennced Field, since deleting a ForeignKey would lead to cascade deletion.

I want to conserve eg the Name of the User related to the object even if the original User object was deleted.

Would something like this work:

```
def set_user_name(self):
    self.user_name = self.user.name
    return None

user = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                         blank=True, 
                         null=True, 
                         on_delete=models.SET(set_user_name))
user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632464/how-can-i-set-user-full-name-in-foreignkey-field-with-user-model-using-on-delete/42634422#42634422). The idea is to store a `CharField` along with `ForeignKey`.

Comment: (I have fixed and updated my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the common practices in relational databases is avoid deleting records that have (or might have) related entities and employ a "soft delete" pattern instead by adding an `active = BooleanField(default=True)` or `deleted = BooleanField(default=False)` field.

Django's built in `User` model has an [`is_active`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) field that can be used for this purpose.

See more resources regarding soft delete in Django in the [delete grid in djangopackages.org](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/deletion/)